# How does Gauntlgrym work?

Tags: neverwinter

In the Neverwinter MMO, there is an endgame area called Gauntlgrym, that is supposed to have PVE and PVP areas.

When my friends and I have ventured there, all we ever see is an area that is full of locked gates and maybe a few AFK guys standing around.  Is there a specific time that events occur there?

I've looked all over net and haven't really been able to find a good answer for how to go about that area, and all the folks that are actually alive and moving in there seem just as lost as I am... Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauntlgrym is active at certain times of the day.  Press L and look at the bottom of the popup window for Upcoming Events.  That will show when the next Gauntlgrym PvP begins.  Be in Gauntlgrym during that time.  You can participate in an initial phase where you gather resources and/or kill monsters, though many seasoned players will only kill a single monster to qualify for the 20v20 PvP phase.

After that initial phase, queue for PvP.  You can be solo or in a party.  Note that you can get in the queue faster if you stand at the large door opposite and down hill from where you first enter GG.  There is a sparky you can interact with to press F to queue before the cut-scene is shown heralding the next phase.

For full details check out

http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Gauntlgrym

Comment: Note that the PVE portion of Gauntlgrym was removed in a recent update.  You now queue for it the same way you would queue for 5v5 arena PVP.